# Why does Beyond TableTop show my half orc barbarian's attack bonus as +7 when it should be +5?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, tools, attack-roll

I was using Beyond TableTop to create a new level 1 Half Orc Barbarian for my new 5e group. I have him using a greataxe with which he is proficient. The attack bonus should be +5, due to being proficient and his strength mod of 3, but the dice roll mechanic is making the roll +7 and I am not sure why. Would anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: You will probably have better luck asking this on the Beyond TableTop forums or submitting a bug report to Beyond TableTop.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculations are right, normally this should be 5 (STR Mod 3 + Prof 2) since there aren't any racial, class or feats that would be adding a bonus to your attack modifier.

I would guess that there's an additional "Attack Bonus" field filled in somewhere that's adding the mystery +2, either under the Equipment or Combat Tabs.

If you're using the premium version of Beyond TableTop, it's also possible that the Rage "power" has been unintentionally edited and is affecting the attack/damage stats of the Greataxe (though I can't check this possibility on the free version).

Comment: I also considered that the calculator is incorrectly adding the +2 to damage, to hit - from rage.

Comment: @ConnorRundle - Good point! I just trialled that in the free version and it doesn't seem to add anything to damage or attack bonus. Rage shows up as a "Power" in Beyond TableTop so that's another tab that could be causing the issue. However, editing those is a premium feature so I can't check that...